# "can't assign to keyword" error with python "except" command

Tags: python-3.7

Do anyone know why do the follow python (3.7) codes:

```
1 # Python backward-compatibility...
2 try:
3    True
4 except:
5    True = 1
6 try:
7    False
8 except:
9    False = 0
10 #
11 # Cheap hack for testing purposes
12 #
```

give the "can't assign to keyword (line 5)" error?

I will appreciate any help.

Best

Comment: `True` and `False` are keywords in Python 3. You can't assign to them anywhere in your code, regardless of being in a `try/except`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#True

Comment: What are you trying to make backwards compatible there? What version of Python does *not* contain the `True` constant?

Comment: The codes come from a script (Caver3_0_1.py) download from http://www.caver.cz/fil/download/plugin/301/caver_3.0_plugin.zip. Do you know why the author wrote in such a way?

Comment: Then it's probably meant for some very old version of Python, and this isn't the only compatibility problem you'll face.

Comment: You could reassign `True` and `False` in Python 2 but you should *not* be seeking backward compatibility with that release stream any more, it's dead as a doornail. Stick to Python 3.

Comment: Could you tell me what are the roles of  reassign True and False in Python 2 and how to achieve the same roles in python 3?

Comment: @YepingSun You can drop those lines completely. They are trying to make sure that `True` and `False` are defined; but they are *always* defined in modern Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign values to the inbuilt python keywords, 'True' and 'False'. Change the name of the variable in line 5, eg:

```
my_var = 1
```

You will also need to change line 9 for the same reasons.

Comment: The codes come from a script (Caver3_0_1.py) download from caver.cz/fil/download/plugin/301/caver_3.0_plugin.zip. Do you know why the author wrote in such a way?